# Azure B2C newbie clarification

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am new in Azure B2C and I would need some clarifications. I am the admin of the B2C

We are working with a partner which is delivering a web app to our customers. We would like our customers to sign-in through AD B2C to the web app.

What is not clear to me:

1. What should be the "Reply URL"? Is it the Web app URL of our partner?
2. What should our partner do in their web app to accept authentication from AD B2C?

Thank you

Slim

Comment: 1. Reply url is used by B2C to redirect to the client app when workflow finish and must be provided by your customer and configured in B2C apps. 2. Your customer should use MSAL library to comunicate with your B2C /authorize or /token endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, that is correct, it is the wep app url of your partner.  "Reply URLs are endpoints where Azure AD B2C returns any tokens that your application requests..."  [Source of quote](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration#register-a-web-app)

2) It depends on the [type of app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview#get-started).  There are lots of sample applications to get developers going.

Comment: Thanks for you response

Answer (score -1):

The reply URL needs to be defined in the web app and also the B2C application within the portal.

in most B2C sample apps it is defined within the web.config as a varialbe with the key  ida:RedirectURl and it is the page that is called to at the end of the policy to return to your app.

It can be any page that exists on your app that you want

```
https://my.site.com/redirect 
https://my.site.com
https://my.site.com/redirect/page
```

are all acceptable

But what ever the URL is it needs to also be defined as a reply URL for the application within B2C

I presume your partner app is initiating the call 
They need to configure B2C within the application using some of the sample apps as guidance and then call one of the policys, at the end of the policy a set of claims is returned to the app which will be used as the users identity